# Adding external images to PDF using iText

Tags: image, pdf, itext

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add an external image (referenced by a URL) to a PDF using iText. Is this kind of thing possible?

The PDF spec in 7.1.5 says you should be able to reference a PDF via a URL by using a URL specification. This is what I've got so far:

```
PdfFileSpecification pdfSpec = 
    PdfFileSpecification.url(writer, "http://www.someurl.com/test.jpg");

StringBufferInputStream sbis = new StringBufferInputStream("");   
PdfStream dict = new PdfStream(sbis, writer);
dict.put(PdfName.FILTER, PdfName.DCTDECODE)
dict.put(PdfName.TYPE, PdfName.XOBJECT);
dict.put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.IMAGE);
dict.put(PdfName.WIDTH, new PdfNumber(100));
dict.put(PdfName.HEIGHT, new PdfNumber(100));
dict.put(PdfName.BITSPERCOMPONENT, new PdfNumber(8));
dict.put(PdfName.LENGTH, new PdfNumber(0));
dict.put(PdfName.F, pdfSpec);

PdfIndirectObject img = writer.addToBody(dict);
```

I know I still need to make sure the color space is added and stuff, but my main concern right now is actually getting this image into the body of the document. I can't figure out how to do this... it seems I can't get a reference to a PdfPage or the resources dictionary or anything. Is this possible using iText?

As a side note, this exercise is useless if I'm going to be presented with a security warning when the view tries to go load the image. Does anyone know if that is the case?

Comment: Also - if this kind of low level operation is not possible in iText, is there another PDF library that makes this easier to accomplish?

Comment: Based on your comment below, what you're really trying to do is track when a document is opened by a user. Here's an example of how to add code to make an active call to a URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099927/tracking-code-into-a-pdf-or-postscript-file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

External content is described in the PDF spec, but almost no PDF processor does actually support them. By now Acrobat 9 has support for it, but I would be very cautious with that feature: Your clients or users may not be able to see the referenced content.

Comment: Hmm, thanks very much, that is helpful. What I'm really trying to do is just get the document to contact a server in the background (was just going to embed a 1px image). I'm working with a client who wants to generate some sensitive documents for their customers and detect if they're being copied all around.

Comment: ...and of course I quickly found out that the Adobe reader has had protections against this sort of thing since version 7 (it shows a security warning, which is a good thing).